# Windows 10 on MacbookPro2,2 drivers missing

Tags: macos, mac, windows-10

I have installed 64-bit windows 10 on to a Macbook Pro 2,2 However there is now no sound.
I am slightly lost as there graphics card is showing as the Microsoft Basic one. 
How can I install the drivers needed to make windows work with the Mac Hardware?

I am not using bootcamp. I wiped the OSX partition and installed Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried installing the applicable sound and graphic device drivers?  What version of Boot Camp are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound not using bootcamp.

Comment: You won't find drivers for that machine for Windows 10 - they don't exist. Maximum supported OS was Windows Vista 32.

Comment: @Tetsujin, well it would seem i'm in a bit of a box right now. Windows 10 is installed and working perfectly fine bar the sound and display not being as hi-res as needed. Any way to get the sound to work?

Comment: @ahervin - No;  If they don't exist you can't install them , and Vista drivers, are not compatible with Windows 10

Comment: The ATI x1600 doesn't have win10 drivers at all, it's long been unsupported. I'm not sure what the audio circuitry is, in terms of how Win would see it - it for sure ain't gonna be a Realtek.

Comment: I've just tried Ubuntu 32-bit on the PC and it works perfectly. It was stupid of me to even put Windows 10 near a 10 year old MBP

Answer (score 0):

You will get all your Windows drivers at boot camp site from Apple here: https://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/downloads/

It's quite a big package for every model.
Note that not all Apple device support Win10.
In case of my MBA it was 2011 or 2012+